# React analyze bundle size

Tags: reactjs, bundle

I have a question - how to analyze bundle size?

I want to get informations how bundle files change in case i will push the commit in gitlab.

I was looking for something like danger.js but it probably doesn't support gitlab.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Answer (score 14):

You can use this script to analyze, without ejecting **create-react-app**

Put `analyze.js` in root of your project ( where the `package.json` is located )

```
npm install progress-bar-webpack-plugin
npm install webpack-bundle-analyzer
```

**analyze.js**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const webpackConfigProd = require('react-scripts/config/webpack.config')('production');

// this one is optional, just for better feedback on build
const chalk = require('chalk');
const ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin');
const green = text => {
  return chalk.green.bold(text);
};

// pushing BundleAnalyzerPlugin to plugins array
webpackConfigProd.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());

// optional - pushing progress-bar plugin for better feedback;
// it can and will work without progress-bar,
// but during build time you will not see any messages for 10-60 seconds (depends on the size of the project)
// and decide that compilation is kind of hang up on you; progress bar shows nice progression of webpack compilation
webpackConfigProd.plugins.push(
  new ProgressBarPlugin({
    format: `${green('analyzing...')} ${green('[:bar]')}${green('[:percent]')}${green('[:elapsed seconds]')} - :msg`,
  }),
);

// actually running compilation and waiting for plugin to start explorer
webpack(webpackConfigProd, (err, stats) => {
  if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Now simply put `node ./analyze.js` in the `package.json` scripts

```
  "scripts": {
      .....
    "analyze": "node ./analyze.js"
  },
```

after that run `npm run analyze`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also accomplish this using webpack stats json file, supported by `create-react-app` and `webpack-bundle-analyzer`.

When running your **build** with `create-react-app`, add the `--stats` flag:

```
yarn build --stats
```

This will create a `build/bundle-stats.json` file, with webpack stats, allowing you to use the `webpack-bundle-analyzer` CLI to analyze this stats.

```
yarn run webpack-bundle-analyzer build/bundle-stats.json
```

reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer#user-content-usage-as-a-cli-utility

tested with CRA latest version at the time: v4

Comment: Above seems only work till certain version of CRA since the `--stats` is no longer usable. For that case we can use this directly without any eject: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-bundle-analyzer

Comment: It's still usable with versions 16, 17 and 18

Answer (score 4):

You can use and configure [`webpack-bundle-analyzer`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) library and use it in your React App  **WITHOUT EJECTING**

1. Add some dependencies by executing `npm install --save-dev progress-bar-webpack-plugin webpack-bundle-analyzer`
2. Create a new folder named `scripts` at the root of your React App.
3. Create a new file `analyze_build_bundle.js` in the `scripts` folder and add the below code in that file

```js
// script to enable webpack-bundle-analyzer
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const webpackConfigProd = require('react-scripts/config/webpack.config')(
  'production'
);

const ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin');

webpackConfigProd.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
webpackConfigProd.plugins.push(
  new ProgressBarPlugin({
    format: `analyzing... [:bar] [:percent] [:elapsed seconds] - :msg`,
  })
);

// actually running compilation and waiting for plugin to start explorer
webpack(webpackConfigProd, (err, stats) => {
  if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

4. Add the `analyze-build-bundle` command in your `package.json` file to run the `webpack-bundle-analyzer` as below:

```js
"scripts": {
    "analyze-build-bundle": "node scripts/analyze_build_bundle.js",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    .....
    ...
}
```

5. Now execute command `npm run analyze-build-bundle`. This will build your app and then start the analyzer local server and you should be able to see the screen as shown in below image

[image]